# How to remove the oldest date folder via batch scripts?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory with multiple folders, that have dates as their filenames:

```
...
03-Wed-11
03-Tue-10
03-Mon-09
...
```

How do I write a batch-script that deletes the oldest folders. Preferably one month old folders? By using their file names, to select the oldest ones.

You can't save a folder with `:` and `/` in it. Thats why The following script. that I used to make the date folder():

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%A in ('date/t') do (
set DateDay=%%A
set DateMonth=%%B
set DateYear=%%C
)
set CurrentDate=%DateMonth%-%DateDay%-%DateYear%
```

If you echo current date like so: `echo %CurrentDate%`, it will display like so: `03-Web-11` date is the Windows system date.

Comment: What do the digits represent?

Comment: @Marichyasana those are the dates month-Day name- day number. Ill post the code that makes those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Need not to set the variable currentYear and currentMonth. It will be automatically set by wmic
set currentYear=
set currentMonth=


REM Setting the currentYear and currentMonth...
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Month^,Year /Format:table') do (
    IF NOT "%%~b"=="" (
        set /a currentMonth=%%a
        set /a currentYear=%%b
        set currentYear=!currentYear:~-2,4!
        set currentMonth=!currentMonth:~-2,4!
    )
)

REM removing folder that are more than one year
for /D %%a IN (*) do (
    set folderName=%%a
    set folderYear=!folderName:~-2,9!

    if !currentYear! gtr !folderYear! (
        rmdir /S /Q !folderName!
        echo Deleted !folderName!
    )
)

REM removing folder that are more than one month    
for /D %%a IN (*) do (
    set folderName=%%a
    set folderMonth=!folderName:~0,-7!

    if !currentMonth! gtr !folderMonth! (
        rmdir /S /Q !folderName!
        echo Deleted !folderName!
    )
)
```

This code will help you to delete for folder that are from the previous month. For example, if you run this code on March 2015 on this folder:

```
...
01-Fri-15 //deleted, since it is more than one month
02-Thu-15 //deleted, since it is more than one month
03-Wed-15 //retained, since the batch program runs on March 2015
03-Wed-11 //deleted, since it is earlier than 2015
03-Tue-10 //deleted, since it is earlier than 2015
03-Mon-09 //deleted, since it is earlier than 2015
...
```

Notice that I use `wmic` to get current date instead of `date \t`. It is because `wmic` allows you to get current date without getting affected by regional settings.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I filled out 2015 under `set currentYear=` and march under `set currentMonth=` but, it deletes every folder, new or old?

Comment: Also tried by typing in 03 under `set currentMonth=`, but it still deletes every folder in it?

Comment: Got it to work, by using 03 and by actually using folders older then one month ;)

Comment: Can i have a minor adjustment to the code tho, is there any way I can automate the `set currentYear=`  and `set currentMonth=` it needs to be automatic!

Comment: This code is automatic. It will automatically set the `currentYear` and `currentMonth` using `wmic` command. It will remove any folder that is earlier than this month :)

Comment: Why the `set currentMonth=` and year? I read it as something I need to `set` manually?

Comment: It is because I initialized it. It will be automatically set after it has completed the first `for /f`. I have updated my post with comments that describe each part of the code